# Inserting matrix into another matrix with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, insert

I want to put a small matrix (p-by-q) called `B` into a bigger matrix (m-by-n) called `A`. How can I do it? Matrix `B` should be put on the right corner of matrix `A`:

[image]

Comment: roughly: `A(end-p+1:end,end-q+1:end) = B;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with basic array indexing, for example:

```
m = 3;
n = 4;
A = rand(m,n)
p = 2;
q = 3;
B = rand(p,q)

A(end-p+1:end,end-q+1:end) = B
```

... assuming that p <= m and q <= n of course.